# selection of radio button in Radio Group in Recycler view in android?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, android-recyclerview

i have Recycler view with radio group and its 4 radio buttons. but when i scroll down the list the middle of item is acting like first one . means if i have 10 items, if select first item button then  the 6 button also got selecting with user selection.

what to do for issue in recycler view. Any Suggestions will be appreciable.
Thanks in Advance.

```
enter code here 
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView quest, timestamp, answer;
    RadioGroup rg;
    RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4;
    Button submit;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        quest = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ques);
        timestamp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tym);
        answer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.answer);
        rb1 = (RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rb1);
        rb2 = (RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rb2);
        rb3 = (RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rb3);
        rb4 = (RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rb4);
        rb4 = (RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rb4);
        rg = (RadioGroup)itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio);
        submit = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.submit);


        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                int clickedPos= (int) group.getTag();
                Log.v("currentpos",""+clickedPos);
                messageArrayList.get(clickedPos).setSelectedRadioButtonId(checkedId);
                int radioId = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(radioId);
                final int currentPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                if (messageArrayList.get(clickedPos).getSelectedRadioButtonId() != -1 && checkedId != -1) {
                    try {

                        String selection = btn.getText().toString();
                        if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase(messageArrayList.get(clickedPos).getAnswer().toString())) {
                            Log.v("TAG", "USER OPTION" + "\t" + selection + "\n" + "CORRECT ANSWER IS" + "\t" + messageArrayList.get(clickedPos).getAnswer());
                           // rg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                          //  answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           // answer.setText("Congrats, you are right. The answer is  " + messageArrayList.get(clickedPos).getAnswer().toString());


                     Toast.makeText(group.getContext(), "YOu are Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                            // rg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            // answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            // answer.setText("Oops, you're wrong, the correct answer is  " + messageArrayList.get(clickedPos).getAnswer().toString());

                            Toast.makeText(group.getContext(), "You are Worng", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        Log.v("hello", selection);
                        String qusnn = quest.getText().toString();
                        Log.v("question", qusnn);
                        String read = "1";
                        try {
                            helper = new DBHelper(group.getContext());
                            database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                            statement = database.compileStatement("update quiz set USERANS =? where QUESTION ='" + qusnn + "'");
                            statement.bindString(1, read);
                            statement.executeInsert();
                            database.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("exception for send data in  table");
                        } finally {
                            database.close();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                        String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
                        Log.v("hello", exceptionAsString);
                    }
                    Log.v("hello" + clickedPos, messageArrayList.get(clickedPos).getSelectedRadioButtonId() + "");


                }

            }});

    }
}


public ChatRoomThreadAdapter( ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList) {

    this.messageArrayList = messageArrayList;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    today = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView;
    if (viewType == SELF) {

        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_items, parent, false);
    }else{

        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.secondlayout, parent, false);
    }


    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Message message = messageArrayList.get(position);
    if (message.getUsans().equals("0")) {
        return SELF;
    }

    return position;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,final int position) {
 final   Message message = messageArrayList.get(position);
    ((ViewHolder) holder).quest.setText(message.getMessage());
    ((ViewHolder) holder).rb1.setText(message.getOpt1());
    ((ViewHolder) holder).rb2.setText(message.getOpt2());
    ((ViewHolder) holder).rb3.setText(message.getOpt3());
    ((ViewHolder) holder).rb4.setText(message.getOpt4());
    ((ViewHolder) holder).answer.setText(message.getAnswer());
     String timestam= getTimeStamp(message.getCreatedAt());
    ((ViewHolder) holder).timestamp.setText(timestam);
   // ((ViewHolder) holder).rg.clearCheck();
  //  ((ViewHolder) holder).rg.setTag(position);
   // Log.e("select" + position, messageArrayList.get(position).getSelectedRadioButtonId() + "");

    ((ViewHolder) holder).rg.setTag(position);
    if (message.getSelectedRadioButtonId()!= -1){

        ((ViewHolder) holder).rg.check(message.getSelectedRadioButtonId());


    }else{
        //your always need to write else condition
        ((ViewHolder) holder).rg.clearCheck();
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messageArrayList.size();
}


public static String getTimeStamp(String dateStr) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String timestamp = "";

    today = today.length() < 2 ? "0" + today : today;

    try {
        Date date = format.parse(dateStr);
        SimpleDateFormat todayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        String dateToday = todayFormat.format(date);
        format = dateToday.equals(today) ? new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a") : new SimpleDateFormat("dd LLL, hh:mm a");
        String date1 = format.format(date);
        timestamp = date1.toString();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return timestamp;
}
```

}

`enter code here`

```
      public class Message implements Serializable {
String id, message, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, answer, createdAt,usans;


public Message() {
}

public Message(String id, String message, String opt1, String opt2, String opt3, String opt4, String answer, String createdAt,String usans) {
    this.id = id;
    this.message = message;
    this.opt1 = opt1;
    this.opt2 = opt2;
    this.opt3 = opt3;
    this.opt4 = opt4;
    this.answer = answer;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
    this.usans = usans;
}
private int checkedId = -1;

public int getSelectedRadioButtonId() {
    return checkedId;
}

public void setSelectedRadioButtonId(int checkedId) {
    this.checkedId = checkedId;
}

public String getUsans() {
    return usans;
}

public void setUsans(String usans) {
    this.usans = usans;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setOpt1(String opt1) {
    this.opt1 = opt1;
}

public String getOpt1() {
    return opt1;
}

public void setOpt2(String opt2) {
    this.opt2 = opt2;
}

public String getOpt2() {
    return opt2;
}

public void setOpt3(String opt3) {
    this.opt3 = opt3;
}

public String getOpt3() {
    return opt3;
}

public void setOpt4(String opt4) {
    this.opt4 = opt4;
}

public String getOpt4() {
    return opt4;
}

public void setAnswer(String answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
}

public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

}
```

Comment: This can be because of the cells getting recycled or reused. Since you already made a selection you bindviewholder method is not resetting the radio group and using the existing one.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Well. If you are using proper MVC for coding then you can add an varable in the recycleview cell model which will hold the radio index selected. whenever you will change the index update this variable for suitable model. Then while binding the cell you can set the selected radio button based on that variable

Comment: thats what only i did there in my code.. once check my code once i updated

Answer (score 1):

Write this in your onBindViewHolder() of adapter class:

holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

I had the same issue and adding this code had helped me.

Edit:The issue is caused because when we scroll in Recycler View the cells gets recycled and in order to make sure the cells don't get recycled, the above method is used.

Comment: Please provide explanation to your answer, doing this helps OP as well as to other people that come with similar issues.

Comment: fixed the problem and created another problem when you select the radio button then scroll down and then up it removes what you have selected

Comment: Avoid this `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);` because your views will never get recycled, and that's not good for the performance of your app, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48263324/7160898) is how you can handle it

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and comments I think you know how `RecyclerView` works especially re-using views.. The only thing you missed is setting view status on all scenarios, what I mean is - you always need to write **`else` part of code**

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            RadioGroup vRadioGroup;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                vRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) itemView.findViewById(R.id.group1);
                //your other stuff
                vRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                        int clickedPos= (int) radioGroup.getTag();
                        messageArrayList.get(clickedPos).setSelectedRadioButtonId(radioButtonID);
                    }
                });
            }
 }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

                Message message = messageArrayList.get(position);

                //your other stuff
                holder.vRadioGroup.setTag(position);
                if (message.getSelectedRadioButtonId()!= -1){
                    holder.vRadioGroup.check(message.getSelectedRadioButtonId());
                }else{
                    //your always need to write else condition 
                    holder.vRadioGroup.clearCheck();
                }

        }
```

hope this helps..

Comment: set `setOnCheckedChangeListener` in your holder class where you are defining your views. not inside `onBindViewHolder` method

Comment: what is item in your code and how can i get it and my problem is not setting radio buttton.if i have 12 items ,if i select first one and scroll down that list ,automatically 6 item is selecting with user click.(that user can not in debug only we can see)

Comment: sorry actually `item` my code object used to test at my end... update the answer check it

Comment: r u observed my code everything .. r u got my problem exactly?

Comment: yes... checkbox is selected other item where actually you are not... its hapening bcz re-using views. solution is  write else part with `holder.vRadioGroup.clearCheck();` when there is not group button is selected.

Comment: remaining thinks are same then?

Comment: no its not working ..i updated with your code ,but no changes its working as bofore

Comment: do you really have two types of views.. Everything looks good and error is something else which i did not find..

Comment: hmm... if i have 12 questions and i selected first question automatically 7 question also got selecting.

Comment: Actually I tried with my own implementation it worked perfectly.. you can check by creating some dummy code..

Comment: by seeing we won't get any error.  but i am updating in db right.. so that i came to know

Comment: r u checked in your code that is it working fine.? then why its not working here?