# Recyclerview add radiobutons programmatically

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I am creating an Android app with Java which displays a question and 3 or 4 options for it (MCQ app). I have used a RecyclerView with a TextView in the XML to hold the question.

However, I am confused on how to create the radio button/checkbox for the option part since those are dynamic. Meaning, a question might have any number of options as radio button from 1 to 6 depending on the entries in the database. Also, few of the question might have checkbox rather than radio button again depending on the DB entries.

Since these are decided at runtime, there is no way I can keep these radiobuttons/checkboxes in the XML file. Initially I tried creating them inside onBindViewHolder method but doing that significantly slows down the scrolling since this method gets called even while scrolling. Since this is a very common use case, I would like to believe the framework must have readily available solution for this which I am yet to discover.

I do not want to add all the possible radiobuttons/checkboxes and play with the visibility of those in runtime.

Comment: First know about how recyclerView works and see this link for some help - http://www.zoftino.com/android-recyclerview-radiobutton

Comment: @Sanjay I did gather some basic understanding on RecyclerView and the example in your link talks about a single RadioButton right? But my use case is different where I come to know about the number of RadioButton only at runtime. So I can not add them in the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your xml file as -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Question Text " />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In Your adapter let you have arraylist of Questions say

```
ArrayList<Question> queList;
```

Instance of Question contain

```
class Question{
String question;
int nubOfOptions;
String[] options;
int selectedOption = 0;
}
```

now First take the id of radioGroup in ViewHOlder as -

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
```

Now in onBindViewHolder you can do as -

```
onBindViewHolder(int position, ....){
  Question que = queList.get(position);
  radioGroup.removeAllViews();
  for(int count=0; count<radioBtnCount;count++){

       RadioButton btn= new RadioButton(context);
       btn.setText("you option");
       if(selectedOption==count+1){
        btn.setCheck(true);
        }
       radioGroup.addView(btn);


    }
}
```

you have to remove all views otherwise you will face problem while scroll.

Comment: I already tried similar thing but without the RadioGroup. I could not use RadioGroup because I wanted to have only two RadioButtons per row which was not possible if I was using RadioGroup. Instead, I created only the RadioButtons in a TableLayout and then unselected other RadioButtons for the same question. The problem with this approach is, since the onBindViewHolder method gets called even on scrolling up and down, this becomes kind of an expensive operation and slows down the scrolling operation. However, as you have suggested, I can try with RadioGroup and see if the performance improves.